# Decimal points in exam class

Tags: exam

I would like to have decimal half points, not fractions, in the `exam` class. How can I obtain this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{exam}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
    \addpoints
    \question[\half] This is a question. 
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one possibility `\renewcommand*\half{.5}`

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[]{exam}
\renewcommand*\half{.5}
\begin{document}
This exam has \numquestions\ questions, for a total of \numpoints\
points and \numbonuspoints\ bonus points.
\begin{questions}
    \addpoints
    \question[\half] This is a question. 
    \question[\half] This is a question.
    \question[5] This is a question.
    \question[5] This is a question. 
    \question[5\half] This is a question.
   \question[\half] This is a question.
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice and easy. Should've seen this one myself.

Comment: This approach works just fine, however, the points in grade table are still in fractionary mode. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: How can you make it to have .5, 0.25 and .75? And also how can you put total points at begining of question?

Comment: I use `\renewcommand*\half{\!,5}` (comma for german documents). The negative space `\!` cancels the space after the integer part. Otherwise you get something like `4 ,5` instead of `4,5`.